# Property or method "info" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to display information coming from a rest API with Vue.js
In a component I want to display users...

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>User Manager</h1>
        <p>
            {{ users }}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the script part :

```
<script>
import {AxiosInstance as axios} from "axios";

export default {
  name: "User",
  data(){
    return{
      users: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers(){
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/users").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.users = response.data;
      });
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getUsers();
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

I obtain unfortunatelly an error message such as : 
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined...

Comment: You should do simply `import axios from "axios";`

Comment: I changed it and i have : Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" + TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined + Cors issue ... but the Cors is a good new :)

Comment: did you install axios?

Comment: yes ... i had a CORS issue in the back end. I solved the issue.

Comment: @davidvera Please consider submitting the solution to your problem as an answer and accepting it. It'll let the rest of the Stack Overflow community know that this question is resolved and may aid others who run into the same problem. Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable here! :)